My angular project freezes and click does not work
Angular project freezes, no clicks work, it gets better when it is refreshed,
no errors appear on the console or anywhere else.
Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions for this problem?
There are functionality-related folders in the domain and each folder has a module and routing module. I am attaching the resolve structure in the project.
Thank you in advance for your answers and suggestions.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AbstractResolve } from '../../../../shared/resolvers/abstract-resolve';
import { AppStore } from '../../../../shared/utils/app.store';

import { ***** } from './*****.service';

@Injectable()
export class *****Resolve extends AbstractResolve {

  constructor(private service: *****,
              router: Router,
              appStore: AppStore) {
    super(appStore, router);
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<*****> {
    return this.resolveAction(this.service.get(route.paramMap.get('id')));
  }
}

hierarchy
src
└── app
    ├── 
    ├── app.component.css
    ├── app.component.html
    ├── app.component.ts
    ├── app.module.ts
    ├── app-routing.module.ts
    └── core.module.ts

project use :oauth2 spingboot 3.3.2 and angular 17.3.8 tool

Thank you in advance for your answers and suggestions.

I suspect it has something to do with the browser. Have you tried changing the browser? I sometimes have the same problem in a specific version of Firefox.
